cgroups v2 : io.latency not exists
When I create a cgroup using sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/my-cgroup, io.latency is not created. Other io files are created, like io.max, io.stat, io.pressure...
The content of cgroup.subtree_control contains io.
When I try to create the file myself, even with sudo, it doesn't work (permission denied).
Do you know what's wrong? Is there something else to enable? Thanks in advance.
Linux distribution: Pop OS 22.04
Kernel version: 6.8.0


Is there something else to enable?

When a documented feature cannot be found with the running kernel, sometimes that's simply because it doesn't have the feature. Either because it's too old or for this case because that was not enabled when it was built:

CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP_IOLATENCY: Enable support for latency based cgroup
IO protection
[...]
Enabling this option enables the .latency interface for IO throttling.
The IO controller will attempt to maintain average IO latencies below
the configured latency target, throttling anybody with a higher
latency target than the victimized group.
Note, this is an experimental interface and could be changed someday.

As seen (as of today only...) in /usr/lib/linux/6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic/config in package linux-buildinfo-6.8.0-76060800daily20240311-generic_6.8.0-76060800daily20240311.202403110203~1713206908~22.04~3a62479_amd64.deb, or if you'd run:
grep CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP_IOLATENCY /boot/config-*

there will be as result # CONFIG_BLK_CGROUP_IOLATENCY is not set.
Pop!_OS (just as its upstreams Ubuntu or Debian) doesn't enable this option (Maybe because it's currently documented as experimental interface in its description?).
If you need it you'll have to find a kernel, or else build a kernel, with this option enabled.

Thanks so much for your help!
